How to find the number of locations within 5 miles of a given address?
I'm working with a list of Lat/Long coordinates for fuel stations and trying to find how many of these stations are within 5 miles of a given location.
We are needing to find how many Alternate stations are within 5 miles of the standard fuel station.

We've been trying multiple formulas to get these values but have not had any success.
The below formula provided the distance from a designated fuel station to an alternative station:
=IFERROR(INDEX(ACOS(COS(RADIANS(90-RD_Stations!$C$3:$C$5000))*COS(RADIANS(90-$R3))+SIN(RADIANS(90-RD_Stations!$C$3:$C$5000))*SIN(RADIANS(90-$R3))*COS(RADIANS(RD_Stations!$D$3:$D$5000-$S3)))*6371,MATCH(SMALL((ABS($R3-RD_Stations!$C$3:$C$5000)^2+ABS($S3-RD_Stations!$D$3:$D$5000)^2)^(0.5),1),(ABS($R3-RD_Stations!$C$3:$C$5000)^2+ABS($S3-RD_Stations!$D$3:$D$5000)^2)^(0.5),0)),0)

Now we tried using the below formula to find count of records less than 5 miles from the original fuel station:
=SMALL((ABS($R3-RD_Stations!$C$3:$C$5000)^2+ABS($S3-RD_Stations!$D$3:$D$5000)^2)^(0.5),1)

I've been able to pull individual distances but could not find a way to get a rank of closest to farthest with a maximum value of 5 miles.

If you are computing the distances, you can use the FILTER and SORT functions to rank them.

Assuming you are calculating great circle distances on a perfect sphere and you don't have FILTER or SORT, try something like this:




Latitude
Longitude










Station 0
37,04271
-122,025












Distance (NM)

Max distance (NM)
Stations within max distance
Top 10


Station 1
34,49374
-118,199

=ROUND(DEGREES(ACOS(ROUND(COS(RADIANS(90-$B$2)),15)*ROUND(COS(RADIANS(90-B4)),15)+ROUND(SIN(RADIANS(90-$B$2)),15)*ROUND(SIN(RADIANS(90-B4)),15)*ROUND(COS(RADIANS(ABS($C$2-C4))),15))),15)*60

5
=COUNTIFS(E4:E6,"<="&G4,E4:E6,">"&0)
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(15,6,$E$4:$E$6/($E$4:$E$6<=$G$4)/($E$4:$E$6<>0),ROWS($I$4:I4)),"-")


Station 2
34,09878
-117,585

=ROUND(DEGREES(ACOS(ROUND(COS(RADIANS(90-$B$2)),15)*ROUND(COS(RADIANS(90-B5)),15)+ROUND(SIN(RADIANS(90-$B$2)),15)*ROUND(SIN(RADIANS(90-B5)),15)*ROUND(COS(RADIANS(ABS($C$2-C5))),15))),15)*60



=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(15,6,$E$4:$E$6/($E$4:$E$6<=$G$4)/($E$4:$E$6<>0),ROWS($I$4:I5)),"-")


Station 3
37,04271
-122,025

=ROUND(DEGREES(ACOS(ROUND(COS(RADIANS(90-$B$2)),15)*ROUND(COS(RADIANS(90-B6)),15)+ROUND(SIN(RADIANS(90-$B$2)),15)*ROUND(SIN(RADIANS(90-B6)),15)*ROUND(COS(RADIANS(ABS($C$2-C6))),15))),15)*60



=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(15,6,$E$4:$E$6/($E$4:$E$6<=$G$4)/($E$4:$E$6<>0),ROWS($I$4:I6)),"-")










=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(15,6,$E$4:$E$6/($E$4:$E$6<=$G$4)/($E$4:$E$6<>0),ROWS($I$4:I7)),"-")










=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(15,6,$E$4:$E$6/($E$4:$E$6<=$G$4)/($E$4:$E$6<>0),ROWS($I$4:I8)),"-")










=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(15,6,$E$4:$E$6/($E$4:$E$6<=$G$4)/($E$4:$E$6<>0),ROWS($I$4:I9)),"-")










=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(15,6,$E$4:$E$6/($E$4:$E$6<=$G$4)/($E$4:$E$6<>0),ROWS($I$4:I10)),"-")










=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(15,6,$E$4:$E$6/($E$4:$E$6<=$G$4)/($E$4:$E$6<>0),ROWS($I$4:I11)),"-")










=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(15,6,$E$4:$E$6/($E$4:$E$6<=$G$4)/($E$4:$E$6<>0),ROWS($I$4:I12)),"-")










=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(15,6,$E$4:$E$6/($E$4:$E$6<=$G$4)/($E$4:$E$6<>0),ROWS($I$4:I13)),"-")



I used my own formula to calculate the distances. You can of course use yours instead. Just note that my results are in nautical miles. You are probably looking for statute miles.
